# Pointwise convergence when $f_n$ is defined as sum of other functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory

I have this problem:
Let  $f: [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Now, define:
$$ f_n (x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}x^{i}(1-x)^{n-i}  f( \frac{i}{n})$$
Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise to f.

I worked (succesfully) the case in which $f$ is the identity map. However, I cant't handle the general case. Could someone give me pointers in how to deal with this kind of problem ? (when the functions in the sequence not only depends on $n$ and $x$, but also in some other index. Thanks in advance!

PD: This problem was left by my teacher to prepare the third exam in my class of probability theory.(the last thing we saw was the Law of large numbers). So maybe there is a natural way of attacking this problem using only probability theory but (honestly) I don't see how.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions

Comment: I see, so it's a famous problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

We could also take i.i.d. random variables $(X_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with probability $P(X_i=0) = (1-x)$ and  $P(X_i=1) = x$. Let now $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n$ X_i. By the strong law of large numbers we have $$\frac{1}{n} S_n \rightarrow x$$
$\mathbb{P}$-almost sure. This also implies convergence in probablity. Since $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, we see that
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k (1-x)^{n-k} f(k/n) = \mathbb{E}[f(S_n/n)] \rightarrow \mathbb{E}[f(x)] = f(x).$$
This gives pointwise convergence. In the proof of the Wikipedia article - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions) - is shown that this convergence is uniformly in x. (This proves the famous Weierstraß theorem on the approximation of functions $C[0,1]$ by polynomials.)